# the sum of all four digit multiples of 6

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation

The sum of all four digit multiples of $6$ is equal to:

A. $8~274~489$

B. $8~247~498$

C. $8~241~996$

Can you help me with this question? I've tried $$S_n= \frac{n(a_1+a_n)}{2}$$
with $n = 1499$, $a_1 = 1002$, and $a_n = 9996$, which gives me $8~243~001$, which is wrong.

Comment: What is your $n$, $a_1$, $a_2$ you used in the formula?

Comment: n=1499 a1=1002 an=9996

Comment: For future reference, here is a [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 2):

You $a_1$ and $a_n$ are correct. However you have incorrectly determined $n$.

Recall that $a_n=a_1+(n-1)d$.

So $9996=1002+6(n-1)$.

$8994=6(n-1)$

$1449=n-1$

$n=1500$

Putting $n=1500$ will give you: $\frac{1500(1002+9996)}{2}=8248500$.

As to why this isn't one of the choice, I don't know. Did you write the question down correctly?

Comment: Thank you! I ve tried that as well but the correct answer must be one of the A B or C :)

Comment: The answer $B$ in the question is the sum obtained by starting at $1008$.

Comment: I've write code to add up all the values and checked it. $8248500$ is correct. Answer $B$ appears to be missing adding on the value $1002$. Was there any other words to the question?

Comment: No there where no more lines! It must be a mistake! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

What is the smallest 4 digit no. divisible by 6?
For this, do 1000/6 = 166.66. Therefore the smallest 4 digit no. div by 6 is 6 X 167.

Similarly for the largest 4 digit no. div by 6: 
9999/6 = 1666.5. Therefore the largest 4 digit no. div by 6 is 6 x 1666.

To find the required sum you need to do the sum $6*\sum_{i=167}^{1666} i$ $=6*[\sum_{i=1}^{1666} i - \sum_{i=1}^{166} i]$

Then apply the formula $\sum_{i=1}^{n} i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ to compute those two sums, which gives me the answer 8,248,500. I recalculated this manually in excel as well, which is producing the same answer. Hence your options may not be correct/there may be more to the question.